# Baixar .txt para memória e ler

Tags: c#

Como baixar TXT na memória, ler e guardar numa variável separadas por `,` as palavras? Queria ler com o slip (acho que é o nome, não me recordo...).

Aqui está, ele baixa o arquivo para RAM:

```
public static bool CheckUpdate()
        {
            System.Net.WebClient wb = new System.Net.WebClient(); //Classe usada para baixar o arquivo de info
            byte[] buffer = wb.DownloadData(remoteVersionFile); //Baixa o arquivo de info para a memória
            System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer); //Cria um Stream para o buffer
            System.IO.StreamReader memReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(mem); //Cria um leitor para o Stream
            Version remoteVersion = new Version(memReader.ReadToEnd()); // Lê a versão do arquivo para uma variável do tipo Versio;
            memReader.Close();
            mem.Close();

            Version localVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version; // Retorna a versão do Assembly (Programa) em execução
            return remoteVersion > localVersion; //Retorna true se a versão na internet for maior que a versão do aplicativo em execução;
        }`
```

Aqui está minha variável, que eu guardo no txt e leio no txt quando ele estiver na RAM:

```
"NoiseFix.cs",
"HPArmorDigital.cs",
"Nomes das ruas.cs",
"Neon.cs",
"Indicador cansaço.cs",
"Sensitivity.cs",
"Strobs.cs",
"Memoryfix.cs",
"MFGTAVH.cs",
"Fogo no escapamento.cs",
"PontosCardeais.cs",
"Xenon.cs",
"MarcasDeTiro.cs",
"Zoom.cs",
"PerPixelLighting.cs",
"Sun.cs",
"Sunlight.cs",
"RainModEffect.cs",
"SnowFlakes.cs",
"Recarregararma.cs",
"Exhaust.cs",
"Skybox.cs",
"Fontfixed.cs",
"camshake.cs",
"turn_indicators.cs",
"particles.cs",
"Skyboxv2.cs",
```

Comment: Você procura o `Split()`?

Comment: Sim eu quero baixar o TXT para a ram e ler ela e salvar numa variavel e seria com Split para ler, a função de baixar a ram já tenho agora preciso só ler a TXT salva na ram....

Comment: Porque você não lê e escreve o Txt com o File.ReadAllLines() \ File.WriteAllLines()? Bem mais simples

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito você quer saber como escrever e ler um txt, sendo na hora de ler separar por ",". Vou deixar um exemplo aqui, veja se te atende.

Escrever Txt:

```
IList<string> lista = new List<string>() { "teste", "teste2", "teste3"};

File.WriteAllLines("caminho_arquivo.txt", lista);
```

Onde, o caminho do arquivo é o arquivo que será criado, e a lista é uma coleção de strings (List ou Array), onde cada elemento da mesma será uma linha do txt.

Ler Txt:

```
string[] lista = File.ReadAllLines("caminho_arquivo.txt");

foreach(string linha in lista)
{
     //Codigo para cada item da lista de linhas do arquivo
}
```

Onde o File.ReadAlllines retorna um Array de strings, sendo formado por cada linha do arquivo.

Exemplo do Split();

```
string nomes = "Joao, Paulo, Sergio, Rodrigo, Pedro";

string[] lista = nomes.Split(',');
```

Onde, o split quebra a sua string no caractere que você informou, retornando um array de string.

Comment: E se tiver uma vírgula no nome ali dentro?

Comment: O texto vai ser quebrado, e se tiver a possibilidade de haver vírgula no nome, terá que ser tratado diferente. Mas na pergunta estava descrito que ele queria separar por vírgula mesmo, então provavelmente isso não acontecerá.

Comment: Ele falou em nomes de arquivos que podem ter vírgula, e se tiver quebra tudo, sem dar erro

Comment: Pode ser, interpretei mal a pergunta então.